# Detect intersection of 2 UIImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift4

Can you help me please to figure out why my code is not working when I try to make a colission between 2 UIImageViews ?

Here is my code:

```
// Creating falling objects
@objc func creating(_ timer: Timer) {

    for (index, imageView) in images.enumerated() {

        if imageView ==  nil {

            let fallingObjectImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PoundImage"))
            fallingObjectImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            fallingObjectImageView.clipsToBounds = true

            let randomX = CGFloat(drand48()) * view.frame.maxX
            fallingObjectImageView.frame = CGRect(x: randomX, y: -30, width: 50, height: 50)
            view.addSubview(fallingObjectImageView)

            images[index] = fallingObjectImageView


            // This IF is not working (I dont know why)
            if (fallingObjectImageView.frame.intersects(playerImageView.frame)) {
                print("HIT HIT !")
            }

            break
        }
    }
}
```

And a photo:
[image]

Thanks !

Comment: What's the point of `if imageView ==  nil {`? I doubt you want that check in there.

Comment: You should use SpriteKit, it have built in collision detection...

Comment: How can I use the function from SpriteKit ? Thanks.

Comment: I use imageView == nil because I reuse my image from an array. And I reposition my image on the top every time when the image hit the bottom edge.

Comment: Do a search on `UIKitDynamics`. I played around with it back in 2014 and had a "billiards table" set up where collisions were detected. This is a *very* old link from 2013, but the concepts are there. https://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial

Comment: Any way to do it using Swift 4 ? All that articles are very old.